# ERROR 500 on certain machines, client side or still server side?

Tags: windows, php, ssl, 500-error

Hope someone can explain if we have to search for a solution on the clients or server side script. This certain link can be opened by many workstations except at one company. The site they have to visit is writen in PHP and requires an SSL/https connection.

The company has 40-50 Windows 7 x64 Enterprise stations with IE11, Chrome & Firefox which can't go to the url, it results in a error 500 message. Tried with 2 internet connections, one with proxy and one without (directly). Within a domain and one within a workgroup. Tried to reset the IE settings to default, cleared the group policy's on the workgroup workstation, without success.

They have 1 workstation on Windows 10 Pro. This machine is able to visit the url without problems on the same network connection mentioned above, with IE11, Edge & Chrome.

And have another workstation on Windows 10 Pro, this one is only able to visit the url in IE11. Edge browser crashes only when visiting the url and chrome results in error 500.

Is there anything browser related what this problem can cause or is it server side?

Comment: Maybe related: http://serverfault.com/questions/819121/500-error-only-in-chrome-works-in-firefox

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP error code 500 (*"internal **server** error"*) is reserved for serverside errors and you'll need to check the servers (error) logs for the cause, possibly after increasing the verbosity/debug level to get sufficient detail. Debugging from the client side alone  will be nigh impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The 500 error message will be coming from the server. You should look in the logs on the server to get more information about what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

500 means it a server-side issue, Please check the error log on the server.